# MongoDB excluding exact match from text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search

I'm using MongoDB's full-text search functionality to search for specific strings in my database.  However, when I use the `$search` operator (I'm using MongoDB's native Node.js driver), the result that I *know* would provide the best match does not appear at all.  For example, I have a string "CSCE-314: Programming Languages". No other string in the database has "CSCE-314" in it.  However, when I search for "CSCE-314", I get results that contain "CSCE" or "314", but not results that include "CSCE" **and** "314":[image: Example Search Query]

The search query is as follows:

```
{
   "$text": {
      "$search": "CSCE-314"
   }
}
```

And I've already double-checked that the matching document exists in the collection.

So what gives?

EDIT: I've included my Mongo `shell` command and the results. It's clear that the `search` collection contains "CSCE-314".

[image: Mongo Shell and Results]

EDIT 2: Search Results Included.

[image]

Comment: does the mongo Shell return the doc? can you post the find doc and query result as well?

Comment: @Saravana edited to be a little more clear.

Comment: and the result for `{
   "$text": {
      "$search": "CSCE-314"
   }
}`  in mongo CLI?

Comment: @Saravana Included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a moron. I was including some additional operations afterwards and one of those operations was, after converting the cursor provided into a sorted array based on score, executing the following:

`sortedCursorArray.splice(10)`

Which extracts all of the results of the array **after** index 10.

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb looking for any words specified in search. Let's say you have 3 documents.

```
{txt:"frog"}
{txt:"worm"}
{txt:"frog worm"}
```

If you search for "from worm" - mongodb will return all 3 documents. Because all of them contains some of words specified in your search.
To find exact string you can use quotes: `'"word1 word2" word3'`.

So this next query will return only one document:

```
DB.my_collection.find({$text: {$search: '"frog worm"'}}); // notice double quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

In your schema define `String` for the field on which you want to perform the search operation.[image]

Comment: I am using MongoDB's native driver. The `name` field in each search document is indexed as a text field, which means it should be searchable, according to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: I have used `text` for the field on which i want to perform `search Operation` it's throughing me an error.But for `String` it is working.Try it once.